# Accessing two different buttons in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to web development and I am learning JQuery now. I have a doubt here. This is the code from W3Schools.com. I would like to know if I add one more button here, how can I run this JavaScript for the click event of the FIRST button only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
<br />
<button>Second Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an ID to the button and put a click event on that id by selecting like this (if button id is 'submitForm') `$("#submitForm")`

In fact, there are many ways you can select elements with jquery, check this out: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

In your specific example, if you don't want to put ID's on buttons, you could use :first to only access the first one, like this `$("button:first")`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
```

to

```
  $("button").eq(0).click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
```

This will only bind to the click event of the first button. See http://api.jquery.com/eq/.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FXhZ8/)**